# Renderizar css/js dentro de uma segunda PartialView

Tags: c#, mvc, partialview

Usando C# MVC5 tenho o arquivo "_Layout.cshtml" que carrega os scripts e css padrões. Cada página em meu site (PartialViews) possuem então seções (Script.Render e Style.Render) para carregar alguns css e scrips separados... Até aqui tudo funciona perfeitamente.

Em uma das páginas que já é uma PartialView possui um botão que ao clicar carrega outra PartialView (dentro da primeira) por meio de um script em jquery, essa segunda PartialView é uma tabela que trás alguns dados.

Exemplo: ao clicar no botão 1 ele trás uma lista de clientes, ao clicar no botão dois ele limpa a lista de cliente e trás uma lista de usuários, ambas listas são  PartialViews.

Meu dilema é, ao carregar a segunda PartialView eu não consigo renderizar/carregar o CSS/JS ta tabela, ela carrega sem CSS/JS nenhum...

View:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="ibox-content">
            <p>
                Profissionais que serão atribuídos ao Usuário:
                <span class="field-validation-error text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Empresas" data-valmsg-replace="true"><br>@ViewBag.ErroCliente</span>
            </p>
            <div id="dvResultado1">
                @{Html.RenderPartial("_TagTabela1", Model); }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

//Carrega CSS da pagina
@section Styles {
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/plugins/chosen/chosenStyles")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/plugins/dataTables/dataTablesStyles")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/plugins/iCheck/iCheckStyles")
}

//Carrega Scripts da pagina
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/chosen")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/dataTables")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/iCheck")
}
```

JQuery que carrega a PartialView "_TagTabela1"

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#NovaTag").change(function () {
        var select = $("#NovaTag option:selected").val();
        $('#dvResultado1').load('@(Url.Action("GetTags1","Clientes",null, Request.Url.Scheme))/' + select);
    })
});
```

Ao que tudo indica, ao carregar a PartialView "_TagTabela" eu não consigo recarregar o CSS/JS novamente, fazendo com que a partial retorne apenas os dados.

Ja tentei colocar os scripts e cs na PartialView, não funcionou.
Tambem tentei colocar o CSS e JS na View principal (_Layout) e tmb não deu certo...

Minha ideia é justamente carregar a segunda partialview e ela carregar junto consigo o css/js especifico dela uma vez que essa tabela tem não só um ccs especifico como tmb um script pra busca na tabela, paginação etc...
Ao entrar na pagina a primeira vez funciona normal, carrega tudo certo, só quando eu clico no botão pra trazer a PartialView que ele "perde" o css e "buga" tudo.

Alguma ideia? Ajuda?

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            bind();
        });

        $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
            bind();
        }); 

        function bind() {
            $('.chosen-select').chosen({ width: "100%" });

            $('.dataTables-Ger').DataTable({
                pageLength: 25,
                retrieve: true,
                responsive: true,
                dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
                buttons: []
            });

            $('.dataTables-Tag').DataTable({
                pageLength: 25,
                retrieve: true,
                responsive: true,
                dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
                buttons: []
            });

            $('.i-checks').iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
                radioClass: 'iradio_square-green',
            });
        }
```

Sempre que recarregar a PartialView ele executa o "bind" que recarrega o js.